# Вставить скриптом

Tags: javascript

Может кто сталкивался, допустим есть какой-то скопированный текст "текст", и его нужно вставить в какую-то выбранную textarea через консоль браузера, можно ли это сделать ? 
Т.е. по сути сэмулировать нажатие ctrl + v

Comment: Правильно ли понял, что пользователь на своём устройстве нажал ctrl + c, а Вам надо сделать ctrl + v? Если да, посмотрите https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF+%D0%BA+%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0&rlz=1C1GCEU_ruBY822BY822&oq=javascript+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BF+%D0%BA+%D0%B1%D1%83&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.9703j1j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Nikita нет, не так
Я что-то скопировал себе в буфер обмена, а скрипт должен вставить в textaera

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть: [старый](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard) интерфейс, [новый](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) интерфейс, [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/2625560) на SO.